# Finding related Transcribe entries for use with Playa and Structure

Tags: playa, structure, transcribe

I have a site set up with 2 languages using Transcribe and Structure and I am now adding a third. One section is a stockist list. The only way I could get this to work, without having to double/triple up on entering stockist information which is the same for each language, was to enter each stockist via the Publish tab (not using Structure) and then link it to the relevant country's state for each language (set up using Structure), using a Playa field (see at the bottom of this question). However, this is very cumbersome and a pain for my client to have to select the same named state for each language.

**English tree in Structure:**

[image: English tree in Structure]

**French tree in Structure**

[image: French tree in Structure]

Now that I am adding another language the problem has become worse. I now need to revisit every single stockist and chose the related state for the NEW language in the Playa field! Surely there must be an easier way? Is it possible to find the ID's of the related entries in the different languages so that I only need to choose the English entry and the French and German (and any other new language) are automatically selected as related? And then add this to my template somehow?

**Current Playa field in the Stockist entry Publish tab. Cumbersome.**

[image: Playa field in Stockist entry]

Thanks in advance for your help - I hope my explanation is clear!

Answer (score 1):

Could you use some kind of entry duplication add-on and only change the desired fields?

Comment: Do you have an entry duplication add-on in mind?

Comment: Hi, MX Cloner is a duplication add-on you could try: [link](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-cloner)